# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have node program which ultimately uses commonjs and therefore my JS files start with a number of **require** statements. I renamed these JS files to TS with the hope that I could incrementally move into Typescript but am getting these errors:

[image]

from the following code:

```
const RSVP = require('rsvp');
const moment = require('moment');
const firebase = require('universal-firebase');
const email = require('universal-sendgrid');
const sms = require('universal-twilio');
const merge = require('merge');
const typeOf = require('type-of');
const promising = require('promising-help');
const _ = require('lodash');

const up = require('./upload');
const audience = require('./audiences');
const message = require('./messages');
```

The locally referenced modules like `upload`, `audiences`, and `messages` *are* likely to define most (all?) of the same modules such `lodash`, etc. I'm guessing that somehow the namespace scope is not being respected between modules but I'm not sure why.

I'm also unclear whether using ES6 `import` syntax would properly transpile to a ES5 **commonjs** "require" module format (this is using Node 0.10.x).

Oh as additional context, my `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "watch": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

> Note: I've seen other people have gotten the *"cannot redeclare block-scoped variable"* error before but none of the conversations seemed to really fully fit my situation. Although i'm quite new to Typescript so maybe I'm making a newbie mistake.

---

Also of note, I noticed some examples of a strange variant of commonjs and ecmascript module formats:

```
import up = require('./upload');
```

This is in contrast to how I'd normally write it as:

```
const up = require('./upload');
```

When I use the "import" keyword, however, it complains that `upload.ts` is not a module:

[image: not a module]

Answer (score 4):

If we look at the [current snapshot of `moment.d.ts` on DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/567ccacf404871ae28602264912dff2d634ff795/moment/moment.d.ts), we'll see that it is a global script file  (as opposed to a module) with a variable named `moment`:

```
declare var moment: moment.MomentStatic;
```

It's considered a global script file because it doesn't import or export anything.

Right now *your* file is also a script file. That might not sound correct, but the idea is that TypeScript doesn't recognize `require` on its own as an import. `require` could technically be any other function.

Instead, you'll need to use a specific syntax for this:

```
import moment = require("moment");
```

All that does is tell TypeScript that this is *actually* an import, and is safe to transform into an import in CommonJS, AMD, UMD, SystemJS etc.

---

As a side note, for TypeScript 2.0, we've updated these `.d.ts` files *not* to be global script files, and instead be authored as modules. If you see the [declaration files for moment in the `types-2.0` branch](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cfe95ce7ba6220f7e22469fd68663c608f1d4ea3/moment/index.d.ts#L8-L9) in DefinitelyTyped, you can see the following lines:

```
declare var moment: moment.MomentStatic;
export = moment;
```

Where `export = moment` is module system-agnostic way of writing `module.exports = moment`.

Comment: I'm still getting my head around TS so I may be missing salient points but I'm not sure what you're suggesting for me. I might add that `moment` actually seems to be working fine ... intellisense is working and no compile errors. This is not true for other npm modules that I'm operating on though.

Comment: @ken Only modules can be imported from, and the only thing that makes a file a module is if it has some sort of indicator that it's a module. That includes imports, exports, or an `export = foo` statement. So if your files are not being resolved as modules, you need to *make them modules* by explicitly using exports. So instead of `module.exports.foo = function() { }`

You'd write

`export function foo() { }`

My suggestion is also to turn your `const foo = require("foo")` calls to use `import foo = require("foo")`.

Comment: Oh i see; yes my modules are all exporting the appropriate functions. I was originally using node/commonjs syntax but have started to use the ES6 "export" modifier.